# iPad Split View Controller - Master View and Detail View contain TableViews

Tags: ipad

I've managed to read some values into a table view and display them in the Master View of a SplitViewController.

What I would like to do is to tap on a row of the Master View and display the details on the detailViewController but in a TableView.

When I tap on the row in the MasterView table, I can't seem to get the detail to populate the detailview TableView.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.  In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath section of the RootViewController class I used [self.tableView reloadData]; and it works perfectly.

Comment: i am also working on the same table views to be appear in both ways ,getting strucked with when i select a row in root view is not getting data to populate in detail view...any suggestions or any example to show..